# Calling a SOAP WebService that uses xsd:anyType

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl, wsdl2java

I need to call a WebService which has an argument that's defined as an array of xsd:anyType, defined like this:

```
<complexType name='ArrayOfAnyType'>
   <complexContent>
      <restriction base='soapenc:Array'>
         <attribute ref='soapenc:arrayType' wsdl:arrayType ='xsd:anyType[]'/>
      </restriction>
   </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

and the return type is also of type xsd:anyType, like this:

```
<message name='RunTask.runTaskInput'>
   <part name='taskName' type='xsd:string'/>
   <part name='args' type='ns2:ArrayOfAnyType'/>
</message>
<message name='RunTask.runTaskOutput'>
   <part name='return' type='xsd:anyType'/>
</message>
```

The WebService is actually a server which can execute lots of different tasks, where the tasks can be configured by the user of the server (and each task has its own specific arguments).

Until now I could generate C# client proxies for this web service using Microsoft's WSDL utility.  The generated C# code could easily be used, provided that I correctly cast all arguments to .Net 'object' type.

I now need to generate a Java client for this web service (and to be honest, I'm only a beginner in Java).  There seem to be a utility called WSDL2JAVA, which I found at http://ws.apache.org/muse/docs/2.0.0/tutorial/01-install-muse.html.  But if I run it, it gives me the following errors:

> WARNING: [ID = 'NoWSRPSchema'] No
>   WS-RP schema found.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: [ID =
>   'NotDocLiteral'] The WSDL operation
>   'runTask' is not doc-literal because
>   it defines a message  with more than
>   one message part for its SOAP Body.
>   The SOAP Body of a doc-literal message
>   should contain one root request
>   element ( with the operation name)
>   with zero or more child elements (the
>   parameters).
>           at org.apache.muse.tools.inspector.ResourceInspector.getInputName(ResourceInspector.java:486)
>           at org.apache.muse.tools.inspector.ResourceInspector.createJavaMethod(ResourceInspector.java:329)
>           at org.apache.muse.tools.inspector.ResourceInspector.getOperations(ResourceInspector.java:570)
>           at org.apache.muse.tools.inspector.ResourceInspector.run(ResourceInspector.java:888)
>           at org.apache.muse.tools.generator.analyzer.SimpleAnalyzer.inspect(SimpleAnalyzer.java:409)
>           at org.apache.muse.tools.generator.analyzer.SimpleAnalyzer.analyze(SimpleAnalyzer.java:348)
>           at org.apache.muse.tools.generator.Wsdl2Java.run(Wsdl2Java.java:178)
>           at org.apache.muse.tools.generator.Wsdl2Java.main(Wsdl2Java.java:270)
>
> SEVERE: [ID = 'CodeGenFailed'] Code
>   generation failed, see the exception
>   information below.
>
> An exception was caught: [ID =
>   'NotDocLiteral'] The WSDL operation
>   'runTask' is not doc-literal because
>   it defines a message wi th more than
>   one message part for its SOAP Body.
>   The SOAP Body of a doc-literal message
>   should contain one root request
>   element (wit h the operation name)
>   with zero or more child elements (the
>   parameters).

I looks to me as the xsd:anyType is not supported here.

What is the easier way to generate a proxy-class for this web service?
Preferably as easy as possible, just like WSDL created the C# proxy for me.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?